# What is the minimum number of trials algorithm for string inversion processing?

Tags: php, algorithm

#### Premises / What you want to achieve

- I want to know the algorithm for the minimum number of trials of inversion processing in a character string with n characters.
- Realized without using standard functions and libraries such as `strrev()`

#### What I tried ・ Source code

- The number of trials was `n times` and `n / 2 times`.
- The number of trials is even smaller than that (I don't know if there is an algorithm)

##### n times

```php
$string = '123456789';
$result ='';

for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($string); $i++) {
    $result = $string[$i] . $result;
}

echo $result. "\n";             // 987654321
echo "count: {$i} times \n";    // count: 9 times
```

##### n / 2 times

- Strictly speaking, even digits are n / 2 times, odd digits are n / 2 + 1 times.

```php
$string = '123456789';
$result = '';

for ($i=0, $j=strlen($string)-1; $i<$j; $i++, $j--) {
    [$result[$i], $result[$j]] = [$string[$j], $string[$i]];
}
if (strlen($string) % 2 === 1) {
    $result[$i] = $string[$i];
    $i++;
}

echo $result."\n";             // 987654321
echo "count: {$i} times\n";    // count: 5 times
```

Comment: What's a "trial"?  What is "string inversion processing"?

Comment: I'm sorry, I used the Google translation.

The "number of trials" refers to the "$i" in the code shown, and refers to the number of times the loop is executed.

The "string inversion processing" refers to the process of inverting a given string.
For example, when the string 12345 is entered, it is displayed as 54321.

Comment: Ideally, the algorithm should have low execution speed and memory consumption.